# Navigation Bar "Cancel"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm currently facing the issue in which if I select on a row in a tableview and go back and press on the "+" button in the navbar, my app will crash. I suspect this may be because I chose the "show modally" option in xcode. Anyways, I may be completely off but here's my code. Please bear with me as I have only picked up coding

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  displayViewController *vc;

  vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    if (path != NULL) {
        vc.pID = path.row;
    }
}
```

This is my prepareForSegue function and the error is happening when I try to set vc.pID to path.row because if I click on the "+" button, it doesn't have a row. Is there a way to not go into the prepareForSegue function if I press the "+" button?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't have a selected row, path should be nil. How it gets to assigning vc.pID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of prepare for segue in objective-c is...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someIdentifierA"]) {
        // get the table view selection, for example
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        // get some part of my datasource (model), for example
        MyModelObject *modelObject = self.datasourceArray[indexPath.row];
        // initialize part of the model on the destination vc
        MyOtherViewController *destination = (MyOtherViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.modelObject = modelObject;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someIdentifierB"]) {
        // same idea here, but different segue to different destination
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        displayViewController *vc = (displayViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.pID = path.row;
    } else if // and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add a test for the segue identifier into prepareForSegue.

The segue property has an identifier value.

```
if segue.identifier == "nameOfSegueIdentifier" { // do stuff here }
```

That way you can run specific code depending on which aspect of your UI is triggering the segue.

**edit**

Sorry, only saw now that you're using objective C. My code is in Swift. Not sure how to implement it in objective C, but the concept will be the same.